# Conditional Formatting Fails on Rounded Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell `P10` has 120 but that's because row 10 is rounded to whole numbers. The actual value entered are 10.1 which is why that row sums to 121. I am trying to highlight `P10` if it doesn't match the sum of the non rounded numbers. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Pic]

The formula is:

```
=SUM($D$14:$O$48)<>!$P$10
```

Comment: Rounded how? With the `ROUND(..., 0)` function or with cell number formatting of `0`?

Comment: Start by removing one of the `=` signs, both of the quotes (e.g. `"`) and the exclamation mark (e.g. `!`).

Comment: Yes, with `round(...,0)`. I tried other variations but excel likes to put back the `=` and `"`.

Comment: Remove the `ROUND` function, use a cell number format of `0` and make adjustments to the formula as I've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a duplicate = sign and lose the quotes. Excel builds those automatically when you first enter something in conditional formatting. Some weird "feature" to try outsmart the user. Also, if this rule goes down by rows, you may not want to have the Rows with $$

try `=sum($D$14:$O$48)<>$P10`